# Entering multiple lines / statements into the IDLE shell?

Tags: python, python-idle

```
x=100
```

ENTER

```
if x == 10:
    print("10!")
elif x == 20:
    print("20!")
else:
    print("I don't know!")
```

It prints *I don't know!* although it's more than one line?
What is the limit of the shell? What does "executed individually" mean - no matter how much code you write, it executes the first line / statement and ignores the rest?

Comment: it prints "I don't know!" because x is neither `10` nor `20`.

Comment: What were you expecting it to print?

Comment: Why does it work when it's multiple lines and they say you can't enter more than one line at a time?

Comment: The IDLE shell *can* receive any number of lines. I do not know where it says that "you can't enter more than one line", but the fact is that it is not confortable to write more than one line of code there because it is not the correct tool for it. If you want to write a program (most probably many more than one line), you should use a text editor (such as IDLE's own editor, VS Code, PyCharm, Sublime etc.).

Comment: Someone here said that lines would be executed individually - what does that mean? "The Self Taught Programmer" said so - "You can only enter one line of code into the shell at once. You cannot copy and paste multiple lines." Althoff, Cory. The Self-Taught Programmer: The Definitive Guide to Programming Professionally (S.16). Triangle Connection LLC. Kindle-Version.

Comment: The `if - elif - else` part counts as one line.

Comment: Okay, so if I entered more than one line at once, it would execute the first line and ignore the rest?

Comment: If you enter more than one statement on the same line you will get a syntax error. But the `if <condition>: <suite> elif <condition>: <suite> else: <suite>` is a (multiline) single statement. Note that it is executed as soon as it is _completely_ entered

Comment: By "same line" you mean before the statement is entered, not the literal line in the shell, right?

Comment: @FelipeWhitaker Unlike line-oriented terminals and consoles, IDLE is designed for entry and history retrieval of multiline *statements*.  Starting with 3.10, the indentation of multiline statements is correct.  Running multiple *statements* at once requires using the editor, as you indicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Python program is a sequence of statements.  In IDLE's Shell, one enters and executes a single statement at a time.  This is much more useful than entering a single physical line at a time, as with python.exe running in a Windows console or *nix Terminal. The text you quoted was talking about the latter, not IDLE.

To understand 'statement', we must start with 'line'.  A [physical line](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#physical-lines) is "a sequence of characters terminated by an end-of-line sequence."  A logical line can be two or more physical lines joined either [explicitly](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining) using a `\` character or [implicitly](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining) using `(), [], or {}` pairs.

A [simple statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html) comprises one logical line. A [compound statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html) usually comprises multiple logical lines, each of which may be more than one physical line.  Your `if` statement is an example of a compound statement.

In IDLE, one enters a complete statement on one or more physical lines.  When a simple statement is complete (when one has entered a complete logical line), IDLE runs it.  Since a compound statement can have an indefinite number of logical lines, one enters a blank line to indicate the end.